# Low microphone volume after using the SoundPad

Tags: windows-10, microphone

After playing sound for the first time with the SoundPad, my microphone broke. At maximum volume setting, it gives practically nothing. I tried to reinstall audio driver, I tried to reinstall audio device, I tried to change volume via windows panel (levels and boost). It didn't help.
I know what I should refer to developer, and I've already done this, but I want to know if someone already faced this problem like me and can help with it much faster. I have windows 10.

Thanks in advance for helping with

Answer (score 0):

Im the "Someone Had Problemo Too"
I finally found the solution to fix this damn app which im installing on steam

If your using Realtek Driver go for :
Search "Device Manager" > Sound, video and game controllers > Click right Realtek(R) Audio > Properties > Driver > Select Rollback Driver (Restart your driver to old version).

If you want the updated RealTek Driver then download the driver first, do this step then go Update Driver with the new version.

If you get notice to restart your computer go for it then it's up to you,

I only found the way to fix Realtek driver only on my ASUS TUF A15 FX506II Gaming Laptop, Thank you for reporting this problem also it has been 1 week on I try using Microphone array which is sound bad lmao.

Hope it fix all, Thanks :)